# Show single Child Category on Custom Post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, categories

Am hoping someone can help me pull out a single custom category name and show it on my custom post page. I've created a new custom post type 'Itinerary' as well as some new custom categories (terms):

Experience

- Water Sports
- Hiking Adventures
- Mountain Biking
  ...

Destination

- Australia
- Canada
- South America
  ...

Each Itinerary has 2 categories applied to it, for example:
Itinerary 'Coastal Walks' is categorised as Hiking Adventures and Australia.

I would like to display in my single itinerary page the name of the child Destination
e.g. Region: Australia (or whatever child destination is selected)

I've tried using this:

```
<?php echo the_terms( $post->ID, 'trip_cat', 'Region: ', ', ', ' ' );   ?>
```

but this displays all the categories selected - I'm trying to display only the child of category Destinations.

Can anyone please help? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_term_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) function.

For Example:

```
<?php
$termID = 10;
$taxonomyName = "region";
$termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can get this function working, but it displays all regions in a list e.g.


Australia
Canada
South America ...


I need the function to somewhow reference the single page, check what location is selected e.g. Australia, and show only that destination.

Answer (score 0):

Stop treating "Destination" and "Experience" as subsets of the same taxonomy type - those should be two separate taxonomy types. (`trip_region` and `trip_theme` maybe?)

Once they're handled as two separate taxonomies, then you can do what you're trying to do:

```
Region: <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'trip_cat' ); ?>
```